# How to dynamically autogenerate Java Beans from WSDL?

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf, wsdl2java

I would like to develop an application to test Web Services, which will automatically generate a JSF form using parameters from the provided WSDL.

The WSDL URL is provided by user and I don't know the names of operations before parsing it. I would like the app to go through the parsed operations and its parameters, and autogenerate the appropriate Java Beans, which I will use to generate a JSF form.

I have tested CXF and JAX-WS, but I think they need to know the operation names before generating Java beans. How to transparently generate Java Beans for any WSDL? Manually running `wsdl2java` is not a solution.

Comment: What about running wsdl2java from inside your program?

Comment: AFAIK, `wsdl2java` generates *.java files with operation names, which I have to dynamically compile and import somehow. How would I do this, not knowing their names before having beans created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CXF does have a "DynamicClient" (see: http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/endpoint/dynamic/JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.html ) that can be used for this.   It parses the wsdl, generated JAXB objects and compiles them, and returns a client that can be used to get the operations and types and such associated with them.

Comment: I've used CXF DynamicClient and it worked just fine:

`JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();

Client c = dcf.createClient(url);

Endpoint e = c.getEndpoint();

ServiceInfo si = endpoint.getService().getServiceInfos().get(0);

BindingInfo bi = si.getBindings().get(0);

BindingOperationInfo boi : bi.getOperations().get(0);`

Comment: I tried with the code given above but not working. it complains about .get(0) for BindingInfo and BindingOperationInfo. could you please please place the working code here.                        Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Maven (and you should be) you can use the CXF codegen plugin to generate classes from the WSDL. There's an example on my blog;

http://qwerky-qwerky.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/programming-without-programming-1.html